# How to print all the elements in an array using a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I have to print an array [1,2,4,6,8,10,23] in separate lines, once using a `for` loop and the other time using a `while` loop.

I did it using a `for` loop as:

```
arr=[1,2,4,6,8,10,23]
for i in arr:
    print(i)
```

I am having trouble doing the same with a `while` loop.

Comment: What is the issue when you using `while` loop? Can you be more specific about your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
arr = [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 23]
i = 0
while i < len(arr):
    print(arr[i])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iter`, try this :

```
arr = [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 23]
iter_arr = iter(arr)
while True:
    try:
        print(next(iter_arr))
    except StopIteration as e:
        break
```

or

```
arr = [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 23]
iter_arr = iter(arr)
try:
    while True:
        print(next(iter_arr))
except StopIteration as e:
    pass
```